# Can't export mysql database

Tags: mysql, export

I've tried this:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > dump.sql;
```

and

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > dump.sql;
```

But all I get is this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u username -p database_name > dump.sql' at line 1
```

I've confirmed that the database exists, andCan anyone point me towards what's going on or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035969/best-mysql-backup-software-for-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqldump` is a command line interface and not a part of SQL. Run the command from bash (or similar).

Comment: Fantastic - thank you.I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

My glasses might need adjustment, but I think you need two dashes on those command line arguments:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u root -p db > db.sql
```